# How can I return data from a Java Hashmap after I find it

Tags: java, hashmap

Here is the code:

```
class thingsToRent
{
    private static HashMap thingsToRent = new HashMap();
    static
    {
        thingsToRent.put("V-1", new String( "Zumba workout video" ) );
        thingsToRent.put("V-2", new String( "Pumping Iron video" ) );    
    }

    public static String get( String serialEntered )
    {
```

This is where I need to return the rental string such as Zumba workout or Pumping Iron,

What do I say where I have the ?

```
        return ?;
```

I have tried return serialEntered but that just gives me the V-1 or V-2 which I

entered into the console using a scanner

```
    }
}

class Video extends Thing
{
    public Video( String serialEntered )
    {
        super( serialEntered );
    }

    public void getDescription( String serialEntered )
    {
        String theRentalFound = (String)thingsToRent.get( serialEntered );
        if ( theRentalFound == null )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Serial Number not found (" + serialEntered + ")");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "Video: " + theRentalFound );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return thingsToRent.get( serialEntered );`

Comment: @sakthisundar.. Actually it's a mere coincidence that OP is invoking the `get` method of `thingsToRent` class, which is exactly similar to how he would access the values in map, which is also named `thingsToRent`. So, I got confused.

Comment: why are you putting things to rent in a static Map??

Comment: Well, its a homework assignment and I didn't know where else to put them.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return thingsToRent.get(serialEntered);
```

will serve the purpose but you don't need that because you have already achieved that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly always code to interfaces. Change `private static HashMap thingsToRent = new HashMap();` to `private static Map thingsToRent = new HashMap();`

Your naming conventions are also a mess, change the class name to something like `RentalItems` and your get method to `getRentableItem` Inside that method you need to access the map with the provided key:

```
public static String getRentableItem( String serialEntered )
{
    return thingsToRent.get(serialEntered);
}
```

Note, you will need to add coode to handle what happens if the item is not there - I'll leave that for you o decide what to do.